# How to left join with JPA returning entities with related entities using Quarkus Panache

Tags: hibernate, jpa, join, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I'm a little bit stuck with a problem.

There is a **Setting** table holding specified settings and a **UserSetting** that holds the value for each setting and user.

```
public class Setting{

    @Column(name = "setting_identifier")
    private String identifier;

    @Column(name = "setting_default_value")
    private String defaultValue;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "setting", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Collection<UserSetting> userSettings = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

```
public class UserSetting {

    @Column(name = "setting_value")
    private String value;

    @Delegate
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Setting setting;
}
```

I want to load all user settings, which are basically **led** by all **settings** entries and optionally **joined** with everything **the user already** has in his **UserSettings** entries.

Using JPA with Panache I get something like this, but then I have the problem of not being able to return both tables **s** and **us**

```
public Collection<UserSetting> userSettings(User user) {
        return find("select ... from Setting s left join UserSetting us on s.id = us.setting.id and us.authUser = :user",
                Parameters.with("user", user)).list();
    }
```

**What do I have to do to bring the joined tables into the form of UserSetting objects with their related Setting object?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it using a **custom constructor** within my UserSetting object, that **initializes the Settings object together with it**.

```
    public UserSetting(String identifier, LocalDateTime createdAt, LocalDateTime updatedAt, String value, Long settingsId) {
        this.value = value;
        this.setSetting(Setting.of(settingsId));
        this.setCreatedAt(createdAt);
        this.setUpdatedAt(updatedAt);
        this.setIdentifier(identifier);
    }
```

and modified the query to reflect the signature of the constructor

```
    public Collection<UserSetting> userSettings(User user) {
        return find("select s.identifier as identifier, 
               us.createdAt as createdAt, us.updatedAt as updatedAt, 
               coalesce(us.value, s.defaultValue) as value,  
               s.id as settingsId from Setting s 
                 left join UserSetting us 
                 on s.id = us.setting.id 
                    and us.user.id = :user",
                Parameters.with("user", user.id))
                .project(UserSetting.class)
                .list();
    }
```